# AJAX response success

Tags: php, ajax

I have function that generates a security password. Onclick of a button I make an ajax call which generates a password. When I try to return value, string or somethings else the ajax do not pass access, but date is updated in database ... I can not find where things don't work.

`Here is button:`

```
 <input type="button" value="generate pass" class="btn btn-info mr50 auth-key-button" onclick="serialkey(<?=$_GET['id']?>)">
```

`Ajax:`

```
<script>
document.querySelector(".auth-key-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector(".auth-key-inputbox").style.display = "block";
});

function serialkey(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'generator.php',
        dataType: 'text/html',
        data:{
            id: id,
            action:'call_this'
        },
        success:function(data) {
            alert(2);
            $( "#result" ).show();
            $( "#divKey" ).hide();
        }

    });
}
```

`File generator.php where it generates the password:`

```
$user = dbUse( "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ".$_POST['id']." ORDER BY id ASC;" );
if($_POST['action'] == 'call_this') {
    function incrementalLetter($len = 1){
        $charset = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        $base = strlen($charset);
        $result = '';

        $now = explode(' ', microtime())[1];
        while ($now >= $base){
            $i = $now % $base;
            $result = $charset[$i] . $result;
            $now /= $base;
        }
        return substr($result, -1);
    }

    function random($length, $chars = '')
    {
        if (!$chars) {
            $chars = implode(range('a','f'));
            $chars .= implode(range('0','9'));
            $time = -microtime(true);
            $hash = 0;
            for ($i=0; $i < rand(1000,4000); ++$i) {
                $hash ^= sha1(substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, rand(1,10)));
            }
            $chars .= $time + microtime(true);
        }
        $shuffled = str_shuffle($chars);
        $shuffled = str_replace('.', incrementalLetter(), $shuffled);
        return substr($shuffled, 0, $length);
    }

    $key = random(6).'-'.random(6).'-'.random(6).'-'.random(6).'-'.random(6).'-'.random(6);
    $unique = dbUse( "SELECT auth_key, COUNT(*) c FROM users GROUP BY auth_key HAVING c>1;" );
    if(count($unique)>0){
        random(6).'-'.random(6).'-'.random(6).'-'.random(6).'-'.random(6).'-'.random(6);
    }else{
        dbUse( "UPDATE users SET auth_key = '".$key."' WHERE id= ".$_POST['id'].";" );
    }
    return $key;
}
```

Comment: So, you make a result element visible but you never fill it with data. Could that be the cause of your grief?

Comment: I'm also not sure why you use native methods to attach event listeners despite having jQuery at hand.

Comment: no ... i tried to fill input value, but nothing ... and i try with return json_encode($data) and in ajax to var data = JSON.parse(data) ... but no result ...

Comment: `alert(2)`? And you're not showing the response anywhere... change to alert(data), for example

Comment: noting .. no errors .. no alert ...

Comment: you're only showing the `#result` element but with no value so add the line `$('#result').html(data)` to include the response of the AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works ... that's how I found a solution if someone else needed it

```
 $data = "";
 $data['key'] = $key;
 echo json_encode($data);
```

and I remove dataType: 'text/html' from ajax and i use var data = JSON.parse(data);
that is ....